# Can't access swift class from Objective-C while the project is in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header, objc-bridging-header

I have a swift project and my initial `UIViewController` is a swift class.

From the initial `ViewController`, I added a new `Viewcontroller` in my `storyboard` and set an **objective-c** class (`FirstViewController.h`) for it.

In my project, I have another **swift class** (`DataManager.Swift`) which is a subclass of `NSObject`.

Now I want to create an instance of this `DataManager.swift` in my **objective-C class** (`FirstViewController.m`). But unfortunately, i couldn't create this instance, giving me an error like - 
`Receiver '`DataManager`' for class message is a forward declaration`

What can I do now to resolve this issue? Is it possible to access *swift class from Objectibe-C class* while project is in swift?

My **FirstViewController.m**,

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
@class DataManager;

@interface FirstViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) DataManager *dataManager;

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   _dataManager = [[DataManager alloc] init]; //This line giving me that error
}
@end
```

My **DataManager.swift** class,

```
import UIKit;

@objc class DataManager: NSObject {
    var a: Int = 0
}
```

My **BridgingHeaderFile**,

```
#ifndef BridgingHeader_h
#define BridgingHeader_h
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should import your swift module into your .m file with this syntax:
`#import "ModuleName-Swift.h"` where `ModuleName` usually is your Project Name.
NOTE: adding `-Swift` suffix is important!

Also `@class DataManager;` will be redundant after import.

Comment: This will be only half a success - judging by OPs Swift code sample, he will also need to make the class `public` and mark all its properties/methods as `@objc public` for them to be visible in Obj-C. This of course depends on Swift version that OP is using - these markers are required for Swift 4.2

Comment: What will happen if the module name has space like "My Project"? Importing "My Project-Swift.h" isn't working here. How should I import this in this case?

Comment: @Nuibb yes, spaces should be replaced with "_"